# Saving multiple records with params.require in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm trying to update multiple records. The form generates fine and submits fine and the data is sent. The records are looked up to update, but no data is ever saved. I have my controller logic, form logic and console dump below. I'm trying to duplicate what Anthony Lewis [put together](http://anthonylewis.com/2011/04/15/editing-multiple-records-in-rails/) but I have a feeling I am not passing the right data into or defining correctly the `params.require().permit()` method. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
class ConfigController < ApplicationController

  def edit

    @services = Service.all

  end

  def update

    params["service"].keys.each do |id|
      @service = Service.find(id.to_i)
      @service.update_attributes!(service_params)
    end

    redirect_to config_url

  end

private

  def service_params
    params.require(:service).permit(:id, :client_id, :client_secret)
  end


end
```

Form code is:

```
  <%= form_for :service, :url => update_config_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal", :method => "put", :remote => true } do %>
    <% @services.each do |s| %>
      <%= fields_for "service[]", s do |service_field| %>
        <fieldset>
          <legend><%= s.name %></legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= service_field.label :client_id, "Consumer Key", :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= service_field.text_field :client_id, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= service_field.label :client_secret, "Consumer Secret", :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= service_field.text_field :client_secret, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag %>

  <% end %>
```

Console reads:

```
Started PUT "/config" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 15:44:08 -0800
Processing by ConfigController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "service"=>{"1"=>{"client_id"=>"testid", "client_secret"=>"testsecret"}, "2"=>{"client_id"=>"testkey", "client_secret"=>""}, "3"=>{"client_id"=>"", "client_secret"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}
  Service Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
{}
  Service Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
{}
  Service Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE "services"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
{}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/config
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: try my answer and inform me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, but perhaps it isn't the best. Let me know if someone has a better idea and I'd be happy to try it!

In the solution I updated my controllers `update` action and the `service_params`.

I passed `id` to `service_params` and called `fetch` method on the `require` method to get the correct params. I noticed that in the console it read `Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3` when it was saving each record indicating the params were an array and I also noticed in @Vijay's solution he tried to narrow down the params as well. After some Googling and console logging I came up with the code below.

```
def update

  params["service"].keys.each do |id|
    @service = Service.find(id.to_i)
    @service.update_attributes!(service_params(id))
  end

  redirect_to config_url

end

def service_params(id)
  params.require(:service).fetch(id).permit( :client_id, :client_secret )
end
```

What do you think?

Comment: I think this is best solution in your case and you should use it because it just works correctly as what you want :D

Comment: Thanks @Kien. Definitely using it and am open to other solutions as well.

Comment: Hi Yavin4. You helped me a lot with this solution ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
params.require(:service).permit( id: [ :client_id, :client_secret ] )
```

Comment: Hey @AndyV this didn't work. It provided the same console output too. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Your strong parameters line should be

```
params.require(:service).permit( [:id, :client_id, :client_secret ] )
```

This permits arrays of values
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and it will work.

Let me know if you get any issue

```
def service_params
  params.require(:service).map do |_, p|
    p.permit(:id, :client_id, :client_secret)
  end
end
```

http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

Comment: Hey @Vijay, this didn't work. Rails console output this
    NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x007fb658812840>):
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:39:in `block in service_params'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:38:in `each'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:38:in `map'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:38:in `service_params'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:28:in `block in update'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:26:in `each'
      app/controllers/config_controller.rb:26:in `update'

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
def update
  Service.update(service_params.keys, service_params.values
end

def service_params
  params.permit(service: [:client_id, :client_secret]).require(:service)
end
```